# Console returns value but Google Tag Manager variable does not

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

When I put `dataLayer[1].ecommerce.checkout.products[0].metric2` in the console, it return the correct value.

However, when I try to extract the value from a Custom JavaScript variable ('Test') in Google Tag Manager, it returns `undefined` when Google Tag Manager is in preview mode.

The JavaScript code:

```
function(){
var basketSize = dataLayer[1].ecommerce.checkout.products[0].metric2;
return basketSize;
}
```

Comment: what question about?

Comment: I'm working on an Enhanced Ecommerce client where the current basket size is pushed to the dataLayer in each step of the check out as 'metric2'

What I would like to do, is to group these values in intervals of 200 (0-200, 201-400, etc.) before handling the data in Google Analytics.

However, Tag Manager does not seem to find the correct value based on the code put into the console.

From my understanding they should read the data in the dataLayer in the same way, though I might be wrong?

Comment: Probably by the time you custom javascript variable is evaluated GTM has pushed a lot of other stuff (gtm.js, gtm.dom and gtm.load events among other things) to the dataLayer so your index is wrong. You should access the dataLayer only via dataLayer variables, anything else is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks, @EikePierstorff!

The thing is, I would like to group the values before sending the data to GA, which the dataLayer variable - from my understanding - does not offer?

When I look up dataLayer[1] in the console it refers to the correct dataLayer and I'm able to lookup the value through the expression above. 

What puzzles me is that the exact same expression does not return a value when setting up i Custom JavaScrip variable..

Comment: Does this happen with every event, that is logged in GTM console?

Answer (score 1):

In case your questions hasn't been answered yet: The thing is you yon't want to reference the dataLayer array inside a dataLayer variable in GTM. This does not make sense, because you already are in the `dataLayer` "namespace". If you reference the field by simply writing `ecommerce./*...*/.metric2` and leaving out the `dataLayer[1]` part, it will work.