# How to push a second product into the data layer with GTM

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm patching enhanced eccommerce reoprting code for Google analytics using Google Tag Manager - by screen scraping data for a checkout step in the process. The code look like this:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('div.field_cart');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(els,function(element){

dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'checkout',
  'ecommerce': {
      'checkout': {
        'actionField': {'step': 1, 'option': 'Visa'},
        'products': [{
            'id': $('div.field_cart')[0].innerText,
        'price': $('div.field_cart')[1].innerText.match(/[0-9]+/),
        'quantity': $('div.field_cart')[2].innerText
     }//,{}...//
    ]
  }
 });
})
```

the problem is that if there are is more than one item - the second ovewrites the first etc instead of getting pushed ... I'd like to know how to **append** a new product to the products object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turns out google tag manager rewired `dataLayer.push()` method to fire events and guard the dataLayer's size. A side effect is that it does not operate as expected. The way to overcome this issue was to push all the scraped product data into a javascript variable and once it was ready, to push that variable into the `dataLayer` as follows:

```
function scrape2DL() {    
    dataLayer.push({'ecommerce.checkout.actionField': {step: 2}}); //action object

    var base = 0; 
    var products=[];
    while (base < $('div.field_cart').length/4) {
       products.push([{id: $('div.field_cart')[4 * base + 0].innerText, price: $('div.field_cart')[4 * base + 1].innerText.match(/[0-9]+/), quantity: $('div.field_cart')[4 * base + 2].innerText}]);
       base += 1;
    }//while 
    dataLayer.push({'ecommerce.checkout.products': products}); // add a product 
 }
 scrape2DL();
 dataLayer.push({event: 'checkout'});      // for GTM triggers
```

However it turns out that it is possible to fetch the products from the datalayer into a javascript variable using the datalayer *get* method and subsequently append more products into it. 
However I ultimately avoided this aproach as it skips the event and size guard check wired into `dataLayer.push()`.

The folowing resources were of some help:

- SO question titled [Console returns value but Google Tag Manager variable does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502800/console-returns-value-but-google-tag-manager-variable-does-notGTM)
- [Google Tag Manager For Nerds](http://www.slideshare.net/SimoAhava/google-tag-manager-for-nerds) by Simo Ahava.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can't push the product alone you need to build object that has all the products inside.

- first step is to retrieve object that is already in dataLayer (even if empty)
- get the products object
- push new item inside
- push the whole object to dataLayer

If you have troubles with any of this steps let me know.

Try to define dataLayer varible first with:

`var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];`

It will take existing dataLayer variable and add use it or if there is none it will make array for it.

Also, I can see that you are using lower case "datalayer". It should be "dataLayer".

I hope this will help.

Comment: Is it added after loading of GTM? Or is it delivered with html? If it is part of some of GTM tags (and thus loaded after loading of GTM) it will brake up events. Just replace it everywhere with var dataLayer =  window.dataLayer || [];

Comment: thanks, the dataLayer was defined on the page, but the data is scraped and pushed via GTM.